# How do you export or retain logs for up to 5 years from Azure?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have a requirement whereby I need to retain logs from Azure for more than 30 – 90 days automatically (the log retention is set by MSFT).

The logs that i need to retain are from approval logs from AzureAD ID Governance.

I have thought about using a PowerShell script that logs its output to a storage account or OneDrive using RunBooks but that seems to open up a log of complexity.

Have you come across any better solutions or ideas that might be better than my current thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [archive the logs to a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/quickstart-azure-monitor-route-logs-to-storage-account) using Azure Monitor. There is a [pricing calculator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-activity-logs-azure-monitor) that shows how much it will cost per year of storage. Unless archiving to a storage account was enabled, it's not possible to retain sign-in logs for more than the default (7 days for Azure AD free or 30 days for Azure AD premium).

[image]

You can use [audit log retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/audit-log-retention-policies?view=o365-worldwide#:%7E:text=As%20previously%20stated%2C%20audit%20records,default%20audit%20log%20retention%20policy.) set how long you want to maintain the logs.